# Transitive dependency from maven BOM?

Tags: maven, maven-bom

I'm working on a utility library that extends the [rdf4j](https://rdf4j.eclipse.org/) framework importing it using its BOM module like:

```xml
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>rdf4j-utils</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>rdf4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!-- core rdf4j dependencies here -->

</dependencies>
```

Would it be possible to make the rdf4j version specified by `rdf4j-utils` available to importing modules so that additional rdf4j modules may be imported from the BOM without specifying the target version? E.g.:

```xml
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>rdf4j-utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>rdf4j-repository-sparql</artifactId>
        <!-- !!! implicit rdf4j version as specified by rdf4j-utils -->
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is exactly solved by creating a bill of materials. So you could create your own BOM which imports the rdf4j one. Then you can put both dependencies in the dependencyManagement section and define the version as a single property to create a minimal maintenance setup.

```
<properties>
  <rdf4j-utils-version>1.0</rdf4j-utils-version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>rdf4j-bom</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>rdf4j-utils</artifactId>
        <version>${rdf4j-utils-version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.rdf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>rdf4j-repository-sparql</artifactId>
        <version>${rdf4j-utils-version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
```

For a more complete example of a BOM, I find the [spring-cloud-dependencies](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/Greenwich.SR3/spring-cloud-dependencies-Greenwich.SR3.pom) one a good inspiration - because it is nice and feature complete being a BOM with a parent pom and importing numerous other BOMs.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can define a property with a name like `<rdf4j.version>` in `<properties>` and use it in the different dependencies.